# split on several chars and include them in the parts

Tags: php, regex, split

I want to split a string on several chars (being `+`, `~`, `>` and `@`, but I want those chars to be part of the returned parts.

I tried:

```
$parts = preg_split('/\+|>|~|@/', $input, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The result is only 2 parts where there should be 5 and the split-char isn't part of part [1].

I also tried:

```
$parts = preg_split('/\+|>|~|@/', $input, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

The result is then 1 part too few (4 instead of 5) and the last part contains a split-char.

Without flags in  `preg_split`, the result is almost perfect (as many parts as there should be) but all the split-chars are gone.

**Example:**

```
$input = 'oele>boele@4 + key:type:id + *~the end'; // spaces should be ignored
$output /* should be: */
        array( 'oele', '>boele', ' @4 ', '+ key:type:id ', '+ *', '~the end' );
```

Is there a spl function or flag to do this or do I have to make one myself =(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split by various delimiters, while keeping the delimiter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437982/split-by-various-delimiters-while-keeping-the-delimiter)

Comment: It's almost a duplicate. I want my split-char to be the 'first on the next' part, instead of the 'last on the current'. Do you know how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$parts = preg_split('/(?=[+>~@])/', $input);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/Xtem8)

Since you want to have the delimiters to be part of the next split piece, your *split point* is right before the delimiter and this can be easily done using positive look ahead.

```
(?=     : Start of positive lookahead
 [+>~@] : character class to match any of your delimiters.
)       : End of look ahead assertion.
```

Effectively you are asking `preg_split` *to split the input string at points just before delimiters.*

Comment: I was almost settling for `preg_split('/([\+>~@])/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`. Cold you explain what you're doing with that `?=`?

Comment: @Rudie: I've added some explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: So using a positive look ahead, the split point is now basically empty? It doesn't split ON a char, but BEFORE it? That's very cool! Is that standard regex or is it a PHP thing?

Comment: @Rudie: You got it right. This is standard regex and most of the regex implementations support it. More on that here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: (My favourite website!) I couldn't find `?=` or `?<=` on there though. Thanks! Could you also explain what happens here: `/(?<=[abcd])(?![abcd])/u`? Only if you're bored =) I can't vote any more up.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing an assignment for the limit parameter which is why it's returning less than you expected, try:

```
$parts = preg_split('/\+|>|~|@/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Now it's even stranger a result... All matches are now arrays with [0] being the capture and [1] being an int..? (Good catch though!)

Comment: From the PHP manual:[Regarding OFFSET_CAPTURE] Note that this changes the return value in an array where every element is an array consisting of the matched string at offset 0 and its string offset into subject at offset 1.

Comment: You read the PHP manual? =) That's funny! Thanks. It helps, but it's not as perfect as _codaddict_'s answer

Answer (score 0):

well i had the same problem in the past. You have to parenthese your regexp with brackets and then it hopefully works

```
$parts = preg_split('/(\+|>|~|@)/', $input, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

and here is it explained: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php#94238

Comment: Actually you don't. But `[\+>~@]` works better, since it's always 1 char.

Answer (score 0):

Ben is correct.

Just to add to his answer, `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` is a constant with value of 2 so you get 2 splits, similarly `PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE` has a value of 4.